# Converting date format: conversion error in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am trying to convert this date to a different format. unfortuantely havnt been successful parsing the date and retaining all the information correctly.

06-Dec-2017 07:14:56.656PM
to
2017-12-06 19:14:56.656

If I try to parse the input date

```
LocalDateTime.parse("06-Dec-2017 07:14:56.656PM",
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("D-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSa"));
```

I get the following error - not sure what it means?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06-Dec-2017 07:14:56.656PM' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field MonthOfYear 1 differs from MonthOfYear 12 derived from 2017-01-06
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.cordys.coe.alf.logger.DBLogger.main(DBLogger.java:366)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: Field MonthOfYear 1 differs from MonthOfYear 12 derived from 2017-01-06
    at java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck(Unknown Source)
```

and if try

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")
        .format((new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSa")
                .parse("06-Dec-2017 07:14:56.656PM"))));
```

It give the following which is confusing, and probably not correct.
2017-01-06 07:14:56:656

Comment: I would suggest that `D` is wrong - From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) - *"D | day-of-year | number | 189"*, I think you mean `d`

Comment: MadProgrammer is right, replace D with d, check this for all conversion symbols: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: That message is tricky alrignt. I believe that it means: from day-of-year 6 (capital `D` in the format pattern string) it gets January (month 1), which conflicts with December (month 12).

Comment: Slightly aside, your experience illustrates an important difference between the old and new API quite well: given an incorrect format pattern string for parsing, the modern API will object so you know something is wrong, while `SimpleDateFormat` will usually just give you an incorrect result and pretend all is well, which I consider more dangerous.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have 2 problems

1. D should be d

> `D` represents day of year
>
> `d` represents day-of-month

2. HH should be hh

> `H` represents hour-of-day (0-23)
>
> `h` represents clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)

Please change `D-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSa` to `d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSa`

For more information , check the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)